# Good games for gods

Tags: gods, games

Imagine a race of all-knowing, all-seeing, all-powerful, eternal gods.

It can get pretty boring. You'll be perfect at any hobby you take up. If you play each other at chess, you will immediately know who is going to win.

Are there any games or hobbies that these gods can take up to stave off the boredom of eternal life?

---

**Assumptions** (In order of precedence)

Eternal-life, omnipotence, omnipresence,  omniscience.

Comment: The play [the game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game)), of course.

Comment: Can you immediately know who is going to win? If omni-ence is treated as ‘infinite capacity to ...’ then the answer isn’t clear cut. Things get weird when you start using infinities.

Comment: Dice? They're so good at it even Einstein jaw dropped!

Comment: Okay but what if two omnipotent gods play each other at chess? If they are both omnipotent that means they are both able to win right?

Comment: What if two omniscient gods try to predict each other's moves? I know your move is based upon reading my mind and knowing my move. So I'll base my move based on your move, which is based on my move, which is based on your move. . . .

Comment: Relevant for opposition of "omnipotent" entities https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87939/is-it-possible-to-have-several-omnipotent-gods

Comment: @Joe Bloggs - I have now imposed a precedence on the omni's. I don't think this invalidates any answers so far but it many clarify.

Comment: playing 5D chess and rolling dice for their D&D roleplay games with realistic simulation they create themselves

Comment: they could play one of those civilaztion building games with people. just hope they're good at it, cause I always end up killing my peoples.

Comment: In "A Game of Blood And Dust", author Roger Zelazny portrayed two omnipotent beings who come across the modern planet Earth and decide to play their favorite game.  One takes on the role of Blood while the other will play as Dust.  The each travel back in time and in turns, make minor changes to Earth's history, killing an inventor here, allowing a teacher to survive a previously fatal accident elsewhere.  After each have taken their agreed upon number of moves, the return to present.  If Earth is barren, Dust wins.  If humanity survives, the game goes to Blood.

Comment: From [help/on-topic], "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." Opinion-based, story-based, not a worldbuilding question... take your pick. VTC.

Comment: To my understanding, omniscient beings should already know what choices will they make and what will be their (even omnipotent) results. IMO, any answers where you apply restrictions and win/lose matters are less valid answers. They already know who will win. I believe these gods would play games solely for entertainment or experience. They might know what path will they take, but temporal restriction to their powers still may give increased enjoyment in terms of fun or re-learning. They know how the chocolate cake tastes and that they will eat it, but that's different than tasting it.

Comment: Scrap the 'increased fun' part. They can make anything they want as fun as they like. It might be about mutual agreement and preferences.

Comment: @Ambu I had trouble choking down all the "omni-" stuff because you're right. Immortal, so there's no risk. Omniscient, so you already know what your opponent is thinking. Omnipotent, so every tug-o-war is a draw. Even if you use mortals, there'd be no temptation to cheat because everyone else would know what you're thinking when you're thinking it. Even the "random nature" of humanity (think "louse races") would be irrelevant as the outcome is already known. Making David Hambling's and Trioxidane's answer the only two valid answers.

Answer (score 6):

**As flies to wanton boys are we to the gods; They kill us for their sport**

[image]

(Image drawn by Paul Kidby for Terry Pratchett's *The Last Hero*. )

Omniscience makes all mortal games a bore. Free will was invented to make games more fun because the pieces behave in unpredictable ways (see note).

At the start of the game all the players choose their win conditions. For example Hephaestus wants "Troy wins to war" and Ares wants "Achilles kills Hector" and Hestia wants "Jim the baker runs out of salt before the war ends". There might be dozens or hundreds of players with a huge range of win conditions.

They agree upon a set amount of interaction for each player. For example a portent costs 1 point. A vision costs 3 point. Electing a champion costs 10 points. Smiting someone costs 20 points, and appearing on the battlefield costs 50 points.

Sometimes there are *portfolio* rules. Each player chooses one or more *theme* and they get discounts for interactions that relate to that theme, and penalties for all other interactions. For example Ares likes to choose the theme of battle.

Once the rules are set up the game begins. The gods watch the world very carefully weigh up the risks and rewards of interacting.

> Depending on how powerful you want your gods to be, free will might just be a convention. Yes the gods can look ahead in time to see how Achilles will react to his cousin/lover dying on the battlefield. But for the purposes of the game they choose not to. That would be cheating.

Comment: The image is, if I remember it rightly, from Terry Pratchett’s graphic novel ‘The Last Hero’ and depicts Blind Io and the gods of Dunmanifestin’ playing games with the lives of mortals (though in this case the game involves a bunch of octogenarian heroes trying to kill the gods themselves)

Comment: Just checked my copy: it is indeed from The Last Hero, though this version cuts out the nude goddess of the afternoon and, sadly, the god of great ideas you didn’t write down and will never remember again.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Thanks. I've attributed it now.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious answer is that they deliberately impose limitations on themselves so their omni-powers cannot be used.

For example, they could incarnate themselves as mortals and contend in our world.

Comment: There is a storyline that human souls are immortal beings who are bored and incarnating as humans to have something interesting to do. In this scenario, the god seeks to educate his children who assume they know everything but lack wisdom to use the knowledge.  Earth is an educational tool and suffering inconsequential to the greater purpose. Sorry, I can't think of the exact reference, could be story or religion.

Comment: IMO, this is one of the only two valid answers on this list: they restrict themselves so they can enjoy surprise in any form.

Comment: @DWKraus: Could you be thinking of the short story ‘The Egg’? There every human is a reincarnation of one nascent god, whose parent explains they have to live every life before they’ll finally emerge into full godhood. The universe is an educational tool for teaching the meaning of life. Quite literally all life.

Answer (score 4):

Omni-things are a rather self-conflicting feats. If you dont have the power to prevent your own omniscience/presence, is it omnipotence? If your omnipotence can stop it, is it omniscience/presence?

Your players will play any game, but use their omnipotence to shroud their own moves while their opponents will deliberately ignore any omniscience/presence they still have about the game. This makes all games a version of poker: its about chances, personality and the moves you can discover. You can allow the players some knowledge of the moves of their enemy or the cards/whatever on the table. Compartimentalized knowledge is your friend, allowing both players to check the result of the moves without revealing to the "playing" compartment of the mind what moves are being made, or a third party God will refree and play out the results of their moves.

Comment: In the light of this, I'll arrange the powers in order of precedence. Specifically omniscience can, if desired, be overruled by omnipotence.

Answer (score 3):

**Boredom is a human invention**

Why would a god get bored in the first place? You're assuming a god from a human perspective. That it can be happy and bored and upset. Why would it be any of these things? Why isn't it just what it is? A god. Even if it would become bored, isn't it omni whatever it wants? Why can't it change itself to whatever?

Comment: IMO, this is one of the only two valid answers on this list: the need for games is irrelevant because the nature of such a being would be to never experience boredom in the first place.